# How to Fix This Issue in WordPress: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare cat_count_span() (previously declared in...) Function in Custom Category Widget

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming, themes

I created custom category widget for my own theme and when I put this widget in main sidebar and footer widget for example i get that error

**Fatal error: Cannot redeclare cat_count_span() (previously declared in E:\xampp\htdocs\repo\wp-content\plugins\consulty-core\widgets\categories\class-consulty-cats.php:157) in E:\xampp\htdocs\repo\wp-content\plugins\consulty-core\widgets\categories\class-consulty-cats.php on line 157**

I used this function cat_count_span to add span tag to posts count and i get it from this link

**[Wrap Post count in a span](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17324/wrap-post-count-in-a-span/)**

Here is the code i used:

```
<?php
/**
 * Widget API: WP_Widget_Categories class
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Widgets
 * @since 4.4.0
 */

/**
 * Core class used to implement a Categories widget.
 *
 * @since 2.8.0
 *
 * @see WP_Widget
 */
class Consulty_Widget_Categories extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Sets up a new Categories widget instance.
     *
     * @since 2.8.0
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array(
            'classname'                   => 'consulty_widget_categories',
            // 'classname'                   => 'widget_categories',
            'description'                 => __( 'A list or dropdown of categories By Consulty.' ),
            'customize_selective_refresh' => true,
            'show_instance_in_rest'       => true,
        );
        parent::__construct( 'consulty_categories', __( 'Consulty Categories' ), $widget_ops );
        // parent::__construct( 'categories', __( 'Categories' ), $widget_ops );
    }

    /**
     * Outputs the content for the current Categories widget instance.
     *
     * @since 2.8.0
     * @since 4.2.0 Creates a unique HTML ID for the `<select>` element
     *              if more than one instance is displayed on the page.
     *
     * @param array $args     Display arguments including 'before_title', 'after_title',
     *                        'before_widget', and 'after_widget'.
     * @param array $instance Settings for the current Categories widget instance.
     */
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        static $first_dropdown = true;

        $default_title = __( 'Categories' );
        $title         = ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : $default_title;

        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-pages.php */
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $title, $instance, $this->id_base );

        $count        = ! empty( $instance['count'] ) ? '1' : '0';
        $hierarchical = ! empty( $instance['hierarchical'] ) ? '1' : '0';
        $dropdown     = ! empty( $instance['dropdown'] ) ? '1' : '0';

        // Custom Required Classes Before Consulty Category Widget

        echo '<div class="sidebar-widget sidebar-categories">';
        echo '<div class="widget-title">';

        // echo $args['before_widget'];

        if ( $title ) {
            echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
        }

        echo '</div>';// End class="widget-title"

        $cat_args = array(
            'orderby'      => 'name',
            'show_count'   => $count,
            'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
        );

        if ( $dropdown ) {
                printf( '<form action="%s" method="get">', esc_url( home_url() ) );
                $dropdown_id    = ( $first_dropdown ) ? 'cat' : "{$this->id_base}-dropdown-{$this->number}";
                $first_dropdown = false;

                echo '<label class="screen-reader-text" for="' . esc_attr( $dropdown_id ) . '">' . $title . '</label>';

                $cat_args['show_option_none'] = __( 'Select Category' );
                $cat_args['id']               = $dropdown_id;

                /**
                 * Filters the arguments for the Categories widget drop-down.
                 *
                 * @since 2.8.0
                 * @since 4.9.0 Added the `$instance` parameter.
                 *
                 * @see wp_dropdown_categories()
                 *
                 * @param array $cat_args An array of Categories widget drop-down arguments.
                 * @param array $instance Array of settings for the current widget.
                 */
                wp_dropdown_categories( apply_filters( 'widget_categories_dropdown_args', $cat_args, $instance ) );

                echo '</form>';

                $type_attr = current_theme_supports( 'html5', 'script' ) ? '' : ' type="text/javascript"';
                ?>

                    <script<?php echo $type_attr; ?>>
                        /*
                        <![CDATA[ */
                        (function() {
                            var dropdown = document.getElementById( "<?php echo esc_js( $dropdown_id ); ?>" );
                            function onCatChange() {
                                if ( dropdown.options[ dropdown.selectedIndex ].value > 0 ) {
                                    dropdown.parentNode.submit();
                                }
                            }
                            dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
                        })();
                        /* ]]> */
                    </script>

                    <?php
        } else {
                $format = current_theme_supports( 'html5', 'navigation-widgets' ) ? 'html5' : 'xhtml';

                /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-nav-menu-widget.php */
                $format = apply_filters( 'navigation_widgets_format', $format );

                if ( 'html5' === $format ) {
                    // The title may be filtered: Strip out HTML and make sure the aria-label is never empty.
                    $title      = trim( strip_tags( $title ) );
                    $aria_label = $title ? $title : $default_title;
                    echo '<nav aria-label="' . esc_attr( $aria_label ) . '">';
                }
                ?>
                <div class="widget-content">
                    <ul class="categories-list clearfix">
                        <!-- <ul> Default Tag -->
                        <?php
                            $cat_args['title_li'] = '';

                            /**
                             * Filters the arguments for the Categories widget.
                             *
                             * @since 2.8.0
                             * @since 4.9.0 Added the `$instance` parameter.
                             *
                             * @param array $cat_args An array of Categories widget options.
                             * @param array $instance Array of settings for the current widget.
                             */

                            /**
                             * put category counts inside span tag
                             * https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17324/wrap-post-count-in-a-span
                             */
                            add_filter('wp_list_categories', 'cat_count_span');
                            function cat_count_span($links) {
                                $links = str_replace('</a> (', '<span>(', $links);
                                $links = str_replace(')', ')</span></a>', $links);
                            return $links;
                            }

                            // ======================================

                            wp_list_categories( apply_filters( 'widget_categories_args', $cat_args, $instance ) );
                            ?>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.widget-content -->
                
                <?php
                        if ( 'html5' === $format ) {
                            echo '</nav>';
                        }
            }

        // echo $args['after_widget'];

        echo '</div>';// End class="sidebar-widget sidebar-categories"

    }

    /**
     * Handles updating settings for the current Categories widget instance.
     *
     * @since 2.8.0
     *
     * @param array $new_instance New settings for this instance as input by the user via
     *                            WP_Widget::form().
     * @param array $old_instance Old settings for this instance.
     * @return array Updated settings to save.
     */
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance                 = $old_instance;
        $instance['title']        = sanitize_text_field( $new_instance['title'] );
        $instance['count']        = ! empty( $new_instance['count'] ) ? 1 : 0;
        $instance['hierarchical'] = ! empty( $new_instance['hierarchical'] ) ? 1 : 0;
        $instance['dropdown']     = ! empty( $new_instance['dropdown'] ) ? 1 : 0;

        return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * Outputs the settings form for the Categories widget.
     *
     * @since 2.8.0
     *
     * @param array $instance Current settings.
     */
    public function form( $instance ) {
        // Defaults.
        $instance     = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array( 'title' => '' ) );
        $count        = isset( $instance['count'] ) ? (bool) $instance['count'] : false;
        $hierarchical = isset( $instance['hierarchical'] ) ? (bool) $instance['hierarchical'] : false;
        $dropdown     = isset( $instance['dropdown'] ) ? (bool) $instance['dropdown'] : false;
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"
                name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text"
                value="<?php echo esc_attr( $instance['title'] ); ?>" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'dropdown' ); ?>"
                name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'dropdown' ); ?>" <?php checked( $dropdown ); ?> />
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'dropdown' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Display as dropdown' ); ?></label>
            <br />

            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'count' ); ?>"
                name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'count' ); ?>" <?php checked( $count ); ?> />
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'count' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Show post counts' ); ?></label>
            <br />

            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'hierarchical' ); ?>"
                name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'hierarchical' ); ?>" <?php checked( $hierarchical ); ?> />
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'hierarchical' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Show hierarchy' ); ?></label>
        </p>
        <?php
    }

}

// Register and load the widget
function consulty_register_custom_cat() {
    register_widget( 'Consulty_Widget_Categories' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'consulty_register_custom_cat' );
```

Comment: Looks like you've probably used `include` or `require` to add the same file twice. Try always using `include_once` or `require_once`. Or possibly you've registered something twice through wordpress's mechanisms (I'm not so familiar with that). Either way, you've managed to get the same function declared twice, seemingly from the same source file...that's what the error is telling you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that named functions are declared inside other named functions, each time the code ran they were declared over and over again.
So I put the function named "**cat_count_span()**" in the **functions.php** file and deleted it from the code in the file listed in the question.
**Now it works fine.**